# How to return a row with 0s if no data is returned?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query that I am trying to get to display rows no matter what. The query returns correct info for what I need if there is some data returned, but in cases where all rows are null, I am getting nothing, obviously, and instead of nothing, I need a row returning all 0's if not.

I have tried using `isnull()` and `coalesce()` to account for this, but I'm not doing it right, apparently. Below is my base query that I need to adjust for this purpose.

```
SELECT
    Vendor
    ,SUM(TotalAssigned) as 'Total Production Assigned Not Completed'
    ,SUM(AssignedFees) as 'Work in process Fees'
    ,SUM(TotalSubmitted) as 'Total Production Submitted'
    ,SUM(SubmittedFees) as 'Submitted Production Fees'
FROM(
    SELECT
        distinct 
        v.ContactFirstName+' '+v.ContactLastName AS Vendor
        ,oi.orderid, oi.orderitemid
        ,CASE WHEN  oi.QueueID > 0 and oi.lastmilestoneid < 70 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TotalAssigned
        ,CASE WHEN  oi.QueueID > 0 and oi.lastmilestoneid < 70 THEN dbo.GetAdjustedVendorFee(oi.OrderID, oi.OrderItemID) END AS AssignedFees
        ,CASE WHEN oim.MilestoneID = 70 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TotalSubmitted
        ,CASE WHEN oim.MilestoneID = 70 THEN dbo.GetAdjustedVendorFee(oi.OrderID, oi.OrderItemID) END AS SubmittedFees

    FROM
    OrderItems oi
    LEFT JOIN OrderItemMilestones oim ON oim.OrderID = oi.OrderID and oim.OrderItemID = oi.OrderItemID
    LEFT JOIN Vendors v ON v.VendorID = oi.VendorID
    WHERE
    oim.MilestoneDate BETWEEN dbo.TruncateDate(dateadd(dd, -1, Current_Timestamp)) and dbo.TruncateDate(Current_Timestamp)
    and oi.VendorID in (105144) 
    and oi.productid not in (105)
)x

GROUP BY Vendor
```

Comment: The problem is in your WHERE clause, you need to have x IS NULL ORed with anything you are filtering on in the LEFT JOINed tables

Comment: I am setting up an a report subscription using SSRS 2008 for a daily report, sometimes there is no data returned but i still have to send out the report.  I cant have it going out blank basically, i am required to have some sort of readable data on the report.

Comment: thanks @DaleM, but what does this mean?  'x IS NULL ORed'

Comment: @wondergoat77 he meant that you've converted you LEFT join into an INNER JOIN because your WHERE clause references a table on the RIGHT. so you should consider `oim.MilestoneDate BETWEEN dbo.TruncateDate(dateadd(dd, -1, Current_Timestamp)) and dbo.TruncateDate(Current_Timestamp) or oim.OrderID IS NULL` or just use an INNER JOIN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to wrap your expression in a CTE and then `UNION ALL` it with

`UNION ALL SELECT NULL, 0,0,0,0  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CTE)`

e.g.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT
    Vendor
    ,SUM(TotalAssigned) as 'Total Production Assigned Not Completed'
    ,SUM(AssignedFees) as 'Work in process Fees'
    ,SUM(TotalSubmitted) as 'Total Production Submitted'
    ,SUM(SubmittedFees) as 'Submitted Production Fees'
FROM(
    SELECT
        distinct 
        v.ContactFirstName+' '+v.ContactLastName AS Vendor
        ,oi.orderid, oi.orderitemid
        ,CASE WHEN  oi.QueueID > 0 and oi.lastmilestoneid < 70 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TotalAssigned
        ,CASE WHEN  oi.QueueID > 0 and oi.lastmilestoneid < 70 THEN dbo.GetAdjustedVendorFee(oi.OrderID, oi.OrderItemID) END AS AssignedFees
        ,CASE WHEN oim.MilestoneID = 70 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TotalSubmitted
        ,CASE WHEN oim.MilestoneID = 70 THEN dbo.GetAdjustedVendorFee(oi.OrderID, oi.OrderItemID) END AS SubmittedFees

    FROM
    OrderItems oi
    LEFT JOIN OrderItemMilestones oim ON oim.OrderID = oi.OrderID and oim.OrderItemID = oi.OrderItemID
    LEFT JOIN Vendors v ON v.VendorID = oi.VendorID
    WHERE
    oim.MilestoneDate BETWEEN dbo.TruncateDate(dateadd(dd, -1, Current_Timestamp)) and dbo.TruncateDate(Current_Timestamp)
    and oi.VendorID in (105144) 
    and oi.productid not in (105)
)x

GROUP BY Vendor)
SELECT * FROM CTE
UNION ALL SELECT NULL, 0,0,0,0  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CTE)
```

Here's [a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/189a3/1000) with a less complicated statement

Comment: If you just need NULLs then this should also work - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/189a3/1013

Answer (score 2):

Another method could be to left join your query, as a derived table, unconditionally to a row of default values and use ISNULL or COALESCE to either return the data from the subquery or fall back to the defaults:

```
SELECT
     ISNULL(sub.Vendor                                   , def.Vendor                                   ) AS Vendor
    ,ISNULL(sub.[Total Production Assigned Not Completed], def.[Total Production Assigned Not Completed]) AS 'Total Production Assigned Not Completed'
    ,ISNULL(sub.[Work in process Fees]                   , def.[Work in process Fees]                   ) AS 'Work in process Fees'
    ,ISNULL(sub.[Total Production Submitted]             , def.[Total Production Submitted]             ) AS 'Total Production Submitted'
    ,ISNULL(sub.[Submitted Production Fees]              , def.[Submitted Production Fees]              ) AS 'Submitted Production Fees'
FROM (
    SELECT
        '' AS Vendor
        ,0 AS 'Total Production Assigned Not Completed'
        ,0 AS 'Work in process Fees'
        ,0 AS 'Total Production Submitted'
        ,0 AS 'Submitted Production Fees'
) def
LEFT JOIN (
    your query
) sub
ON 1=1  -- unconditionally; almost the same as CROSS JOIN
;
```

This is almost like a cross join, but, unlike the latter, is guaranteed to return a non-empty dataset.

Comment: Well, yes, good point, normally with RIGHT JOIN it should be easier. But in this case the query contains grouping. Adding the default row using a right join would likely require adding new columns to the existing GROUP BY. I thought it would be better (simpler) to just use the present query as a derived table instead. And once it's a derived table, there won't be much difference whether I put it on the left side of a right join or on the right side of a left join.

Comment: I am not sure I got the GROUP BY argument. As the only column that I added [ONE] is not included to the output, it does not need to be in `GROUP BY`. How `RIGHT` or `LEFT` affects that?

Answer (score 2):

This can be a simpler solution (remix of @AndriyM):

```
SELECT
    Vendor
    ,SUM(TotalAssigned) as 'Total Production Assigned Not Completed'
    ,SUM(AssignedFees) as 'Work in process Fees'
    ,SUM(TotalSubmitted) as 'Total Production Submitted'
    ,SUM(SubmittedFees) as 'Submitted Production Fees'
FROM (
    SELECT
        distinct 
        v.ContactFirstName+' '+v.ContactLastName AS Vendor
        ,oi.orderid, oi.orderitemid
        ,CASE WHEN  oi.QueueID > 0 and oi.lastmilestoneid < 70 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TotalAssigned
        ,CASE WHEN  oi.QueueID > 0 and oi.lastmilestoneid < 70 THEN dbo.GetAdjustedVendorFee(oi.OrderID, oi.OrderItemID) END AS AssignedFees
        ,CASE WHEN oim.MilestoneID = 70 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TotalSubmitted
        ,CASE WHEN oim.MilestoneID = 70 THEN dbo.GetAdjustedVendorFee(oi.OrderID, oi.OrderItemID) END AS SubmittedFees

    FROM
    OrderItems oi
    LEFT JOIN OrderItemMilestones oim ON oim.OrderID = oi.OrderID and oim.OrderItemID = oi.OrderItemID
    LEFT JOIN Vendors v ON v.VendorID = oi.VendorID
    WHERE
    oim.MilestoneDate BETWEEN dbo.TruncateDate(dateadd(dd, -1, Current_Timestamp)) and dbo.TruncateDate(Current_Timestamp)
    and oi.VendorID in (105144) 
    and oi.productid not in (105)
) x RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 1 as ONE) T ON 1=1
GROUP BY Vendor
```

**sqlfiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/189a3/1024

Comment: This is not entirely equivalent to my solution, because this may return NULLs, while my solution is also about substituting the NULLs with specific default values. No-one, however, said that the defaults must indeed be provided by the query itself, so, it is only fair for me to vote this one up.

Comment: On the other hand, with your method the default values could, of course, be provided in the SELECT clause directly. Perhaps my failing to see that before was the reason for the little misunderstanding between us. If you provided them in your answer, then your stating of its being a remix of mine would be closer to the truth. :)